# How to extract string between quotes, with a delimiter in Snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a bunch of fields which are double quoted with delimiters but for the life of me, I'm unable to get any regex to pull out what I need.

In short - the delimiters can be in any order and I just need the value that's between the double quotes after each delimiter.  Some sample data is below, can anyone help with what regex might extract each value? I've tried

```
'delimiter_1=\\W+\\w+'
```

but I only seem to get the first word after the delimiter (unfortunately - they do have spaces in the value)

```
some content delimiter_1="some value" delimiter_2="some other value" delimiter_4="another value" delimiter_3="the last value"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is returning a varying numbers of values from the regex function. For example, if you know that there will 4 delimiters, then you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR for each match, but if the text will have varying delimiters, this approach doesn't work.

I think the best solution is to write a function to parse the text:

```
create or replace function superparser( SRC varchar )
returns array
language javascript
as
$$
  const regexp = /([^ =]*)="([^"]*)"/gm;
  const array = [...SRC.matchAll(regexp)]
  return array;
$$;
```

Then you can use LATERAL FLATTEN to process the returning values from the function:

```
select f.VALUE[1]::STRING key, f.VALUE[2]::STRING value
from values ('some content delimiter_1="some value" delimiter_2="some other value" delimiter_4="another value" delimiter_3="the last value"') tmp(x),
lateral flatten( superparser(x) ) f;

+-------------+------------------+
|     KEY     |      VALUE       |
+-------------+------------------+
| delimiter_1 | some value       |
| delimiter_2 | some other value |
| delimiter_4 | another value    |
| delimiter_3 | the last value   |
+-------------+------------------+
```